# TFS Workspaces across VS 2010 and 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-2012, workspace

I am currently developing on Visual Studio 2012 RC using TFS Preview for source control.  I would like to create an SSIS Integration project, which requires me to use Visual Studio 2010.  However, when I connect to TFS from VS 2010, it automatically creates a new workspace and does not list the VS 2012 workspace.

If I issue the `tf workspaces` command from the VS 2010 command prompt, I see only the VS 2010 workspace, and if I issue the command from the VS 2012 command prompt, I see only the VS 2012 workspace (both indicate the same colleciton is being used).

Is there some way I can get VS 2010 to see the VS 2012 workspace?  I would prefer not to have to have two copies of source code just to be able to use VS 2010 for the SSIS project.

Comment: Have you installed [VS 2010 SP1 TFS 2012 Compatibility GDR](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)?

Comment: @KMoraz I'm not sure that's relevant -- maybe it is -- but, I have the issue described with that patch installed.  The purpose of the patch is to allow VS 2010 to connect to newer versions of TFS (like the cloud hosted VisualStudio.com for example). -- It's more of an authentication/protocol update.  It doesn't magically add support for local workspaces in 2010, however.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

TFS 2012 introduces a new concept called *local workspaces*, which differ subtly from the behavior of workspaces in previous versions of TFS (the old default behavior is now called a *server workspace*.)  Local workspaces do not require read-only files and instead allow files to be edited without checking out from the server, and they are intended to be more suitable for small to medium sized workspaces.  For this reason, *local workspaces are the default* in TFS 2012.

Local workspaces, however, are *not* compatible with TFS 2010 and TFS 2010 clients will not be able to use a new local workspace.

You can convert the workspace that you created with your VS 2012 client to a server workspace.  In the Edit Workspace dialog, select Advanced, and you can change the type from a Local to a Server workspace.

At that point, you should be able to connect with VS 2010 and choose that TFS workspace.

(Note that it's not sufficient to use `tf workspaces` as that will return a cached copy of your workspace list - you will need to connect to the server either with Visual Studio 2010 or with a `tf.exe` command that talks to the server.)

Comment: Perfect answer by Edward Thompson however I just wanted to add to the answer with these two great reading resources. [TFS 2012 Workspaces Part 1](http://osnabrugge.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/tfs-source-control-2012workspaces-part-1/) [TFS 2012 Workspaces Part 2](http://osnabrugge.wordpress.com/2012/09/03/tfs-source-control-2012workspaces-part-2/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help in attaching workspaces created in VS2010 to VS2012, even though it sees the mappings are there. Would be nice if the same workspaces can be used with both to avoid the disk gnashing of deleting a bunch of files only to copy them back again. Grr.

Comment: Server workspaces are compatible between VS 2010 and VS2012.  Have you refreshed your workspace cache?  If you're having trouble, perhaps provide details in a separate stackoverflow question.

Comment: @EdwardThomson - Yes, I just tried that. No dice. VS2012 can use the workspace and make new mappings, but there's something missing in the VS2010 mapping that doesn't recognize that TFS folders are mapped to local disk. Things show up with Local Path: Not mapped in Source Control Explorer. Maybe I'll post a question later, but this has already taken up more time than I wish to devote to it.

Comment: But, How Can We Close That. I Want To Create With Server Settings Default.

Comment: @Saarp -- I had the same issue -- No matter what I changed the settings to (i.e. server/private instead of local), VS2010 couldn't see it -- and I would delete the 2013 workspace, but it would just get recreated automatically somehow -- I ended up creating a new workspace in 2010, and then, to my surprise, VS 2013 could see the 2010 workspace, so I switched over to it in 2013 -- then I deleted the old one that 2013 kept auto-creating. -- So far so good!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the Location="Server" property mentioned in other answers/comments, the File Time property must be "Current", as shown below.

Workspaces created in Visual Studio 2012/2013 with **either** Location="Local" **or** File Time="Checkin" are not visible/usable in Visual Studio 2010.

[image]