# Add existing folder to Team Foundation Server 2010 that already exists for other Team Foundation Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, visual-studio-2012, source-control-explorer

[image]I am workign with a central Team Foundation Server (2010) and I connect to it from my workstation. On my workstation I use both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. I have installed both have the Team Explorer 2010 and 2012 and the latest patches and hotfixes.

I need to use both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 because I am developing both .NET 4.5 code and SQL Server Reporting Server reports for SQL Server 2012.

I can configure both instances of Visual Studio to connect to TFS, I mapped my workspace in Visual Studio 2012 and I can interact with Source Control. I tried configuring Visual Studio 2010 to use the same working folder, I can connect to TFS, I can see the source control folder, but when I try to map it to the same local folder I get the following error message:

> > **Map**
> >
> > The working folder "C:\TFS\Example" is already in use by the workspace JohnDoesPC; Doe, John on computer JohnDoesPC

I tried configuring the workspace mapping through the dropdown in the Source Control Explorer:

1. Team Explorer><kbd>project</kbd>><kbd>Source Control</kbd>>Map Window>(Set Local Folder)

And I tried it through the Source control menu under the File menu:

2. Go <kbd>File</kbd>><kbd>SourceControl</kbd>><kbd>Manage Workspaces</kbd>>(Highlight my showing workspace)><kbd>Edit</kbd>>Try to add existing folder.

What am I missing? Do I need to map my solution folder to two different local folders? That would be very confusing and inconvenient!

The simplest way to put this is that I want two versions of TFS to point to the same local location.  Is that possible?  Or should I be creating a new project up just for my SSRS reports?

EDIT: See pic for more detail:

Comment: Yes and I will look at your answer on Monday.  I am new to TFS.  I basically just want what you stated in your answer, so you assumed correctly.  I can get the info from the server by connecting to it but did not check that the workspaces matched exactly.  So I believe it is the Team Explorer for 2010 that may be the issue.

Comment: Check that both instances of Visual Studio are using the same workspace name. I suspect you'll have two (or more) namespaces in the dropdown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS Workspaces across VS 2010 and 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278842/tfs-workspaces-across-vs-2010-and-2012)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that in both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 the same work space name is selected. If you cannot see the workspace of 2012 in Visual Studio 2010, check the advanced workspace settings of the workspace in 2012. Ensure that the workspace type is [set to server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx#Admin_Settings).

When both Visual Studio versions are using the same workspace name, they should be able to see and use each others file mappings as well.

This is what the settings in 2012 should look like:
[image: Workspace configuration 2012]

And that workspace should be visible in 2010 as well:
[image: Workspace configuration 2010]

Make sure you select the same workspace name in both versions of Visual Studio:
[image: Same workspace in both Visual Studios]

Comment: This does not work, it states: "ERROR The workspace (myworkspace); (myname) already exists on computer (mycomputer)".  I cannot see a 'local' option to set on Team for 2010.  Basically 2010 is blank, if I try to add a new or existing option it gives this error.  Basically 2010 has nothing and cannot allocate a connection locally to store data relating to TFS.

Comment: No, the type needs to be set to *server*.  Local workspaces aren't supported in 2010.

Comment: Ahhh, that did it.  I guess it makes sense you need a server workspace to have different local spaces that it can track.  It messed up my project settings somehow on one of my BI SSRS projects but I was able to create a new one and import and then rebind to source control.  Now it works is the import thing, thanks a lot jessehouwing.