# Why does "tf history ." claim there is no working folder in my mapped TFS directory?

Tags: tfs

I am trying to modify my project so that on build it queries for the current TFS changeset for the local directory and uses that to form the build number (using http://florent.clairambault.fr/insert-svn-version-and-build-number-in-your-c-assemblyinfo-file as a reference).

Since we currently are not using team build or any continuous integration for this particular project at this time I plan to use:

```
tf history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W
```

However, when I test this command out using the visual studio command prompt in my project's directly (where I work from TFS) it claims:

> There is no working folder mapping for xxxxxxxx

The folder is shown as mapped in my workspaces in Visual Studio's Source Control Explorer (shows as the local path), and when I edit my workspace.

Why is the command line utility claiming there is no working folder when it is?

Comment: Mismatch between `tf.exe` version and Visual Studio version?

Comment: Ahhhhh, you are correct sir.  Good call.  The command prompt that was loading was for VS 2010 not 2012.

Comment: @Edward Thomson - wow, that is some good debugging skills. How did you think of that?

Comment: Did that resolve your problem? If so you should put it as the solution so it can be upvoted.

Comment: Yep that was the solution.  I am waiting to see if Edward puts it as an answer so I can give him his due points.

Comment: @SoftwareCarpenter: just a good guess!  :)  This is a leading problem between Visual Studio and Team Explorer Everywhere clients not seeing each others workspaces, a problem that I happen to be intimately familiar with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will see this error message if you are using Visual Studio 2012 (and the corresponding Team Explorer 2012 client) and you are using `tf.exe` from Team Explorer 2010.

TFS 2010 clients store their local *workspace cache* in a different location on-disk than TFS 2012 clients.  Thus, if you are to create a workspace with a TFS 2012 client, the TFS 2010 client cannot see that workspace data until it has connected to the server and populated its own local client cache.

It sounds like you're okay with using the TFS 2012 version of `tf.exe`, so I would make sure that your `PATH` contains an entry to that one first, and this should resolve your problem.

If you really wanted interoperability between the two versions, you would need to make sure to connect to your TFS server from both clients in order to make sure the workspace cache was complete for both.  However make sure that you are using *only* server workspaces in this case, as [TFS 2010 cannot connect to a TFS 2012 local workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278842/tfs-workspaces-across-vs-2010-and-2012/11287076#11287076).