# TFS 2012 Workspace across VS 2012 and VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently moving a solution which contains VS 2010 and VS 2008 projects to TFS 2012, and I have checked in the code through VS 2012 Source Control Explorer.

But when I open the project in VS 2010 or VS 2008 it seems like the files are not mapped in source control.

I know that we cannot map the same workspace for VS 2012 in VS 2010, please could anyone suggest any solutions?

I have already tried the following

1. I converted the workspace type from local workspace to Server Workspace and I was able to map the same location in both VS 2010 and VS 2012, but when I open the project in VS 2010 it seems like it is not mapped to source control.
   ([TFS Workspaces across VS 2010 and 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278842/tfs-workspaces-across-vs-2010-and-2012) )
2. Having separate workspaces 
   ie, C:\TFS (for VS 2012) and C:\TFS2010 (for VS 2010). This has not worked as VS 2010 is failing to load the projects.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is VS 2010 up to date? As this normaly does work fine (same setup here)...

Comment: I hope so, Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50938 SP1Rel

Comment: Do you have the update from Alex answer installed?

Comment: I just installed, and have converted the workspace type to Server Workspace. Now I'm getting error messages when opening the 2010 projects.

Comment: And the messages are?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS Workspaces across VS 2010 and 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278842/tfs-workspaces-across-vs-2010-and-2012)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for your reply.

I managed to resolve this issue by removing the old source control (Serena Dimensions) references from the project files (the workspace type is **Server Workspace**.)

Many thanks all of you.

Answer (score 1):

You need this for 2010 to work correctly http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking in the upgraded solution at same location or different location in TFS?

You should be able to use the same workspace irrespective of different Visual Studio versions provided both solution paths are mapped in same workspace.

Comment: No, we cannot set the same workspace in VS 2010 and VS 2012 for TFS 2012.

Comment: As you are using the Server workspace which is supported by old versions of Visual Studio, I think it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, its Server workspace. But when opening the projects I'm getting the following message. "An error occurred registering this project with Source Control".

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2013/05/29/server-workspaces-vs-local-workspaces.aspx).

> Because local workspaces use a local data store that only VS 2012 and
>   later know how to read and write, local workspaces are invisible to VS
>   2005, 2008, and 2010 clients which might be installed on the same
>   machine as your VS 2012 instance. If you want to share your workspace
>   between VS 2012 and VS 2010 on the same machine, then local workspaces
>   aren’t for you and you should convert your workspace back to a server
>   workspace so that VS 2010 can see it.